# Binary Tree- Data Structures

Tags: c++

How does a tree know when to stop adding elements on one side?

I have the code but am unable to grasp the logic. I am new to coding and need help.

```
class node {
public:
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

node* buildtree()
{
    int d;
    cin >> d;
    if (d == -1)
        return NULL;

    node* root = new node(d);
    root->left = buildtree();
    root->right = buildtree();
    return root;
}
```

The o/p and everything is alright but how and why??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

Comment: Depends on the tree structure.  On some trees, when the new node is lesser than the present tree node, it gets inserted on the left subtree, otherwise it gets placed on the right subtree.  A binary tree could insert the new value on the left subtree if greater.

Answer (score 0):

> How does a tree know when to stop adding elements on one side?

thanks to

> ```
> if (d == -1)
>     return NULL;
> ```

the recursion stops when you enter -1.

Examples :

- If you call *buildtree()* and enter -1 that returns an empty tree (a NULL pointer)
- If you call *buildtree()* and enter 0 then -1 then -1 that return a single node with *data* 0 without left/right (they are NULL pointer)
- If you call *buildtree()* and enter 0 then 1 then -1 then -1 then -1 that returns the node with *data* 0 having a left node with *data* 1 without left/right nodes and the return node have no right node
- Etc

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the concepts of data input and tree insertion.

```
Node * tree = nullptr;
void build_tree()
{
   int number;
   while (std::cin >> number)
   {
       insert(tree, number);
   }
}
```

The `insert` function would insert the value into the tree depending on `number`.

Your function is traversing the tree and inserting whatever the User types in; not maintaining the order of the nodes in the tree.